# if statement function to many argumnets

Tags: bash

I've overlooked my program for any mistakes and can't find any. Usually when I run into a mistake with BASH the interpreter is off on where the mistake is. I'm trying to customize this script from SANS InfoSec Using Linux Scripts to Monitor Security. Everything is fine until the part where the check function looks at the different protocols. When I uncomment them I get the error: ./report: line 41: [: too many arguments. Here is the program...

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
  echo "Must be root to run this script!"
  exit 1
fi

##### CONSTANTS -
report=/home/chron/Desktop/report.log
#router=/home/chron/Desktop/router.log
red=`tput bold;tput setaf 1`
yellow=`tput bold;tput setaf 3`
green=`tput bold;tput setaf 2`
blue=`tput bold;tput setaf 4`
magenta=`tput bold;tput setaf 5`
cyan=`tput bold;tput setaf 6`
white=`tput sgr0`

##### FUNCTIONS -
pingtest() {
ping=`ping -c 3 localhost | tail -2`
loss=`echo $ping | cut -d"," -f3 | cut -d" " -f2`
delay=`echo $ping | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -d"." -f1`

if [ "$loss" = "100%" ]; then
  echo -n $red$1$white is not responding at all | mail -s'REPORT' localhost
  echo 'You have mail in /var/mail!'
  echo `date` $1 is not responding at all >> $report
elif [ "$loss" != "0%" ]; then
  echo $yellow$1$white is responding with some packet loss
else
  if [ "$delay" -lt 100 ]; then
    echo $green$1$white is responding normally
  else
    echo $yellow$1$white is responding slow
  fi
fi
}

check() {
if [ "$2" != "" -a "$2" $3 ] ; then
  echo -n $green$1$white' '
else
  echo -n $red$1$white' '
  echo `date` $1 was not $3 >> $report
fi
}

##### __MAIN__ -
pingtest localhost # hostname or ip

echo "Server Configuration:"
check hostname `hostname -s` '= localhost'
check domain `hostname -d` '= domain.com'
check ipaddress `hostname -I | cut -d" " -f1` '= 10.10.0.6'
check gateway `netstat -nr | grep ^0.0.0.0 | cut -c17-27` '= 10.10.0.1'
echo

echo "Integrity of Files:"
check hostsfile `md5sum /etc/hosts | grep 7c5c6678160fc706533dc46b95f06675 | wc -l` '= 1'
check passwd `md5sum /etc/passwd | grep adf5a9f5a9a70759aef4332cf2382944 | wc -l` '= 1'
#/etc/inetd.conf is missing...
echo
#echo "Integrity of Website:"
#check www/index.html `lynx -reload -dump http://<LOCALIP> 2>&1 | md5sum | cut -d" " -f1 '=<MD5SUM>'

#echo
echo "Incoming attempts:"
#lynx -auth user:password -dump http://10.10.0.1 >> $router 2>&1
check telnet `grep \ 23$ $PWD/router.log | wc -l` '= 0'
check ftp `grep \ 21$ $PWD/router.log | wc -l` '= 0'
check ssh `grep \ 22$ $PWD/router.log | wc -l` '=0'
check smtp `grep \ 25$ $PWD/router.log | wc -l` '=0'
check dns `grep \ 53$ $PWD/router.log | wc -l` '=0'
echo
```

Some of the lines are commented out for later tweaking. Right now my problem is with the protocols. Not sure what's wrong because it looks like to me there are 3 arguments for the function.

Comment: Can you explain what you think is happening on the errored line :- if [ "$2" != "" -a "$2" $3 ]

Comment: You are missing an operator, but `-a` is considered obsolete. Use `[ -n "$2" ] && [ "$2" ... "$3" ]` instead (for whatever operator should be between `$2` and `$3`).

Comment: if second argument is not empty then print second arg and third arg

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend. And in the future, build a [**M**inimal, **C**omplete, **V**erifiable **E**xample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with only the smallest amount of content needed for others to successfully reproduce your problem when asking questions with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last three calls to `check`, you are missing the required space between the operator and the operand.

```
check ssh `grep \ 22$ $PWD/router.log | wc -l` '=0'
check smtp `grep \ 25$ $PWD/router.log | wc -l` '=0'
check dns `grep \ 53$ $PWD/router.log | wc -l` '=0'
```

The final argument to all of these should be `'= 0'`.

However, this is not a good way to structure your code. If you really need to parameterize the comparison fully (all your calls use `=` as the operation), pass the operator as a separate argument. Further, written correctly, there is no need to pre-check that `$2` is a non-empty string.

```
check() {
  if [ "$2" "$3" "$4" ] ; then
    printf '%s%s%s ' "$green" "$1" "$white"
  else
    printf '%s%s%s ' "$red" "$1" "$white"
    printf '%s %s was not %s\n' "$(date)" "$1" "$3" >> "$report"
  fi
}
```

Then your calls to check should look like

```
check hostname "$(hostname -s)" = localhost
check domain "$(hostname -d)" = domain.com
check ipaddress "$(hostname -I | cut -d" " -f1)" = 10.10.0.6
check gateway "$(netstat -nr | grep ^0.0.0.0 | cut -c17-27)" = 10.10.0.1
```

etc

Run your code through http://shellcheck.net; there are a lot of things you can correct.

Comment: So I'm still having an issue with the protocols. I checked shellcheck.net and it was saying there is some kind of parser error with the if statement. The check gateway still comes back as red even though the output of the command is 10.10.0.1.

Comment: Did you fix the calls? `check ssh `grep ...` '=0'` tries to run `[ "<output of grep>" "=0" ]`, which is different from `[ "<output of grep>" = 0 ]`.

Comment: I got that space in after the operator. I think the protocols aren't working because the book is using some kind of router log file I don't actually have.

Comment: Since grep is for files I don't have a file recording those things. Hahaha... no wonder. It comes back with no file or directory as the error. So it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my other problem. I changed it up a bit just to see what's going on.

```
router=/home/chron/Desktop/router.log

check() {
if [ "$2" "$3" "$4" ]; then
  printf "%s%s%s" "$green" "$1" "$white"
else
  printf "%s%s%s" "$red" "$1" "$white"
  printf "%s %s was not %s\n" "$(date)" "$1" $3" >> report.log
fi

check gateway "$(route | grep 10.10.0.1 | cut -c17-27)" = 10.10.0.1

check telnet "$(grep -c \ 23$ $router)" = 0
check ftp "$(grep -c \ 21$ $router)" = 0
check ssh "$(grep -c \ 22$ $router)" = 0
check smtp "$(grep -c \ 25$ $router)" = 0
check dns "$(grep -c \ 53$ $router)" = 0
```

Comment: Just to remind, I'm pulling this out of a book. I can't seem to find out exactly how 22$ is interpreted by bash. What is it?

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the log file that the book is using. Just dawned on me. I don't have that same log file. So...

Comment: `22$` is not interpreted by bash, it's interpreted by grep. In this case, it's a regex meaning that you're counting the number of lines that end in `22`.